# Screen: Keep programs running after shutdown

Tags: shutdown, gnu-screen

Is it possible to run screen on my linux box, and resume activites **after** shutting down?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with all updates installed and Screen version 4.00.03jw4 installed from the Ubuntu repositories.

Ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

GNU screen looks like magic, but it cannot keep programs running when you shut down the machine. If you want a program like `irssi` (an IRC client) running even when the machine is shut down, you'll need a different machine that is powered on and to which you can connect using `ssh`. This machine can be a remote server or your local router. (assuming it can run Linux of course)

Comment: Cheers @Lekensteyn I should have realised that being a advanced Linux user myself, I'll see if I can use my 1&1 SSH server instead.